# Is there a way to block my website in IE and let it work in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, browser

I have code on my website that IE seems to have a lot of trouble and keeps crashing and stuff,  The good news is there is a 99.9% chance that the users that will be on my site will not be using IE, so I want to make my website available to all other browsers except IE.  If they are using IE I just want a message saying something like "Unfortunately this website is not available in this browser" or something like that.  Can I do this, if so, How?, I'm guessing JavaScript, right?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap your page content in conditional comments.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
<body>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <p>Sorry, Internet Explorer is not supported.<p>
    Use <a href="http://firefox.com">Firefox</a> instead.
    <![endif]-->

    <![if !IE]>
    <p>The page content for all other browsers.</p>
    <![endif]>
</body>
```

Comment: @Ben, you should also select this as an answer if you feel it is the best response. That will improve your acceptance rank as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do it on the server side using the `User-agent` request header, that way you don't have to send all your page or could even send an alternate version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the navigator.appName variable in java script to have conditional if in your code to not display to internet explorer.  A tutorial website is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in pure HTML:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
    all your code
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I would really suggest to fix what's broken instead. Otherwise, I suggest conditional comments(but rather not the whole body, just to refresh to a different website)

Comment: Well I dont think there is a way to fix it, Im using some CSS which is im guessing is CSS3, and its to rotate a couple of DIVs 45 degrees, so in IE it seems to fail, im guessing im out of date maybe, im not sure, just as easy to block it haha

Comment: If it's only a cosmetic problem you should allow IE users to see it but display a message saying the site doesn't work well in IE.

Comment: Well thats the thing, without the DIV's been at a 45 degree angle the site would not work for its purpose at all

Comment: You're in luck, css is invented for this kind of issues. Different styling, same semantics! So all you need is an IE stylesheet or something like a html.ie selector.